# Lambda S3 ObjectCreated not triggering on commandline aws s3 cp

Tags: amazon-s3, aws-lambda

In Lambda, I put a trigger on `ObjectCreated:*` event. It works when using SDK. But when I use commandline mass upload using `aws s3 cp`, it doesn't trigger at all. Any ideas?

Comment: That should definitely work. Are you sure the function isn't erroring out due to some difference in the event being passed to it? Did you check the CloudWatch logs for the function?

Comment: There are no errors or triggers in the cloudwatch graphs and logs. It's as if it just didn't run at all.